# Remote validation in MVC3.0

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I have a remote validation on one of the fields of a class:

```
    [Remote("IsCityUnique", "City", AdditionalFields = "Onvan", HttpMethod = "POST", ErrorMessage = "City name isn't unique.")]
    public string CityName
    {
        get { return _CityName; }
        set
        {
            if (_CityName != value)
            {
                _CityName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("CityName");
            }
        }
    }
    private string _CityName;
```

And in my Controller:

```
    public JsonResult IsCityUnique(string Cityname)
    {
        ....
        List<City> citylist = cr.GetAll().ToList();
        return Json(!citylist .Any(c => c.CityName== Cityname));
    }
```

the "IsCityUnique" will fire correctly , but validation method in Edit & Create is diffrent.How can I fire proper method when I'm in create mode or Edit mode? I think if I can pass action name to this method then I can manage it.But I didn't know how can I pass action name to remote method.Otherwise , can you suggest me a proper way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MVC 3 Remote Validation, problem with duplicate check in Edit view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7078075/mvc-3-remote-validation-problem-with-duplicate-check-in-edit-view)

Comment: It is very stupid way because a method , seperate controller class!!!There isn't any way?

Comment: Calling a solution "very stupid" isn't usually the best way to get some help.

Comment: Tnx for your solution,but seems it is only way for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So while I would still recommend using separate ViewModel for edit and create, which has more architectural advantages than just remote validation, you *should* be able to do what you want using the `AdditionalFields` property, which you seem to be using in the property but not on your validation handler.

I'm not in a position to test this, but if you *really* wanted to do it this way, then you might be able to do this following:

To your ViewModel add:

```
public bool IsEditing { get; set; }
```

When you are on your editing action set this to true (and false on your creation action).

```
[Remote("IsCityUnique", "City", AdditionalFields = "IsEditing", HttpMethod = "POST", ErrorMessage = "City name isn't unique.")]
public string CityName { get; set; }
```

In your view, you may have to render `@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.IsEditing)`, and then your validation handler should become:

```
public JsonResult IsCityUnique(string Cityname, bool IsEditing)
{
    if(editing) { /* Do editing Logic */ }
    else { /* Do other logic. */ }
}
```

Something like this *should* work, but I'm not in the position to test it right now. But you would really probably be better of observing a separation of concerns and figure out how to divide the responsibilities between editing and creating a domain object.

Comment: @Shayan it is - if you want to ignore 'why' you have two view models as recommended by basically everyone here.

Answer (score 1):

Use two view models, each has a different property name with its applicable remote validation method. This is yet another of the many reasons to simply use view models for each view. So you should have a view model for Create and for Edit.